# How to access global picklist value set in apex code

Tags: apex, picklist, global-picklist

I want retrieve Global picklist Value Set and assigned them into a drop down box using apex.

How could I resolve this?

Comment: If you really want to access the Global Picklist value Set, you will need to use an API call

Comment: Tooling API for example

Comment: Thank you kurunve & Peixoto !!